# Is it possible to create a prototype content UITableview in a xib file without using storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xib

[image]

Now I am developing a chating app using pars, without storyboard. I need to create a prototype content `UITableview` in my chat .xib file. Kindly guide me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You can do that.

Drag and drop UITableView on your xib and Select UITableView "Attribute Inspector". Then Select Content as "Static Content" if you want manage UITableView Cell content through xib. Otherwise you can go for delegate methods implementation.

UITableView "Attribute Inspector" >> Content property

[image]

Comment: Sorry I can't see the content option in the attribute Inspector

Comment: please check above screenshot

Comment: Please see my screenshot in my question

Comment: there have something wrong , I would like to suggest you delete UITableView and again drag drop new one

Comment: Even if you are not getting that option then Please try to add Table View Cell on UITableView , its should be work for you